# Vue JavaScript Mutiselect option value not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

I have an issue In using vue multiselect to select multiple items from an API call
but I'm getting blank even response is printing on console.

Multiselect:

```
<multiselect mode="tags"
    :searchable="true"
    :createTag="true"
    :multiple="true"
    v-model="genre"
    :value= 'genreoptions.id'
    :options= 'genreoptions.title'
    :show-no-results= "false">
</multiselect>
```

Data:

```
data () {
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      fname: '',
      lname: '',
      bday: '05/05/1996',
      gender: 'Male',
      emailid: '',
      bio: '',
      profileimg: null,
      awards: '',
      websiteurl: '',
      profession: null,
      tags: null,
      label: null,

      genreoptions: '',
      genre: []
 
    }
  },

  getBasic () {
      getApi.get('/createartist',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'image/jpeg'
          }
        }
      )
        .then(res => {
          console.log('first', res.data.genre)
          this.genreoptions = res.data.genre
          this.options.professionoptions = res.data.profession
          this.options.tagsoptions = res.data.tags
  })
}
```

But Now I'm getting nothing In vue template
but as data is printing on console also I'm getting 0 value vue console.

I tried everything but I'm not able to resolve this issue.

```
 [![Attactched Image Here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @shob for helping me out to solve this issue

```
v-if="options.genreoptions"
  mode="tags"
  :searchable="true"
  :createTag="true"
  multipleLabel="true"
  label='title'
  v-model="genre"
 :options="options.genreoptions"
 valueProp="id"
 :show-no-results= "false"
 /multiselect>
```